# How to print filled shapes in the terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, c, special-characters

How to print a filled circle or shapes in the terminal like:

[image: How to print filled shapes in the terminal?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That shape you show might be the Unicode character ●.

Also, from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12982461/1424395

> http://www.unicode.org is the place to look for symbol names.
>
> ● BLACK CIRCLE        25CF
>
> ⚫ MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE 26AB
>
> ⬤ BLACK LARGE CIRCLE  2B24
>
> or even:
>
> NEW MOON SYMBOL   1F311

Also, this question might interest you: [Printing filled shapes in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167974/printing-filled-shapes-in-terminal)

Comment: It is, in fact, U+25CF.

Comment: @myradio I thought that they were using some sort of program to print that filled circle shape. Like you said, it turns out that it was just a character. Thanks!